# Unable to get the latest published

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, publish

I have set up a empty ASP.NET Core Web App project. I have publihsed it and let it run in a docker container. So far so good.

Now I have added a button and published that web page. Running it from Visual Studio (pressing the "Docker" run button) the latest greatest occurs. However, after having build the other docker and running the web page, is still shows me the old one.

Clearing the cache or using incognito mode didn't helped. I changed between "Debug" and "Release", I deleted "bin" and "obj", rebuild everything, published, build docker,... still the old web page occurs.

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delete the container and image in the Containers Window.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022#use-the-containers-window
[image]

Comment: Indeed. I forgot to rebuild the container. Instead I simply opened the previous one, thus the old website. Adding "--build" to the command helped a lot: 
docker-compose -f my-docker-composition.yml up -d --build